# How to apply the chain rule in vector calculus with inverses and with respect to 1-dimensional parameters?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, chain-rule

Given the following matrices and vectors, I am trying to derive the gradient of equation (1).

$t \in R ,\quad S \in R^{N \times N}, \quad y \in R^N, \quad Q = tS $ and $Q$ is invertible

$\frac{\partial y^TQ^{-1}y}{\partial t} \tag{1}$

Equations (2), (3) and (4) come from the matrix cookbook:

https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

$\frac{\partial a^TX^{-1}b}{\partial X} = -X^{-T}ab^TX^{-T} \tag{2}$

$\partial (X^{-1}) = -X^{-1}(\partial X) X^{-1} \tag{3}$

$\frac{\partial a^TXa}{\partial X} = aa^T \tag{4}$

Given all of the above, I tried to apply the chain rule, but I see two different approaches to this. The first one, described in (5), uses identity (2), whereas the second one, described in (6), uses the identities (3) and (4).

$\frac{\partial y^TQ^{-1}y}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial y^TQ^{-1}y}{\partial Q} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} = -Q^{-T}yy^TQ^{-T}S \tag{5}$

$\frac{\partial y^TQ^{-1}y}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial y^TQ^{-1}y}{\partial Q^{-1}} \frac{\partial Q^{-1}}{\partial t} = yy^T(-Q^{-1}\frac{\partial Q}{\partial a}Q^{-1}) = -yy^TQ^{-1}SQ^{-1} \tag{6}$

Are these results the same? And if yes, why?

Furthermore, are they correct? Both results are in $R^{N \times N}$, whereas I expected the gradient (1) to be in $R$, since $y^TQ^{-1}y \in R$ and $t \in R$.

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't $Q^{-1}=(aS)^{-1}=1/a\cdot S^{-1}$ as $a$ is a real number?

Comment: Yes, but does that change anything? Thanks

Comment: It makes the function defined on the reals.

Comment: I think that both (5) and (6) are still in $R^{N \times N}$

Comment: Isn’t your function sending the real number $a$ to the real number $y^T(aS)^{-1}y$?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how this changes the fact that the results in (5) and (6) are still in $R^{N \times N}$.

Comment: Because the derivatives from (2) on were taken in respect ta a vector, not a number.

Comment: The derivative is just $-1/a^2y^TS^{-1}y$.

Comment: Perhaps my notation was not very clear, so I changed the $a \in R$ in (1) with $t \in R$. In (2), (3) and (4) $a$ and $b$ are vectors, whereas $X$ is a matrix. In (5) and (6) I differentiate with respect to t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's write things out explicitly. You have a function 
$$
f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R : t \mapsto  y^TQ^{-1}y\tag{1}
$$
where $y \in \Bbb R^n$ is a fixed vector, $S$ is a fixed invertible $n \times n$ matrix, and 
$$
Q = tS.
$$
Now 
$$
Q^{-1} = \frac{1}{t} S^{-1}
$$
so we can rewrite formula 1 as 
$$
f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R : t \mapsto  \frac{1}{t^2} y^TS^{-1}y\tag{2}
$$
where $y^T S^{-1} y$ is a constant --- a single real number. The derivative of $f$ is thus (without using the chain rule or anything, really!)
$$
f'(t) = \frac{-2}{t^3} y^T S^{-1} y.
$$

As for why your book of formulas doesn't lead to this result...I'm not willing to help out there, because I don't think that applying formulas without understanding them is within the realm of "mathematics".

But @MichaelHoppe is completely correct in noting that these formulas are for derivatives with respect to a vector argument, which you do not have (you have a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$). Applying them willy-nilly is unlikely, therefore, to lead to a useful result.